# unexpected force closing in my application

Tags: android

I was following a tutor, where I found my application was getting force close though I followed the tutor properly.
Here are my file,

**EmployeeList.java**

```
package samples.employeedirectory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class EmployeeList extends ListActivity {

        protected EditText searchText;
        protected SQLiteDatabase db;
        protected Cursor cursor;
        protected ListAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
    }

    public void search(View view) {
        // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                                                new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                this, 
                                R.layout.employee_list_item, 
                                cursor, 
                                new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
                                new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmployeeDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

**EmployeeDetails.java**


package samples.employeedirectory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EmployeeDetails extends Activity {

        protected TextView employeeName;
        protected TextView employeeTitle;
        protected TextView officePhone;
        protected TextView cellPhone;
        protected TextView email;
    protected int employeeId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.employee_details);

        employeeId = getIntent().getIntExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", 0);
        SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT emp._id, emp.firstName, emp.lastName, emp.title, emp.officePhone, emp.cellPhone, emp.email, emp.managerId, mgr.firstName managerFirstName, mgr.lastName managerLastName FROM employee emp LEFT OUTER JOIN employee mgr ON emp.managerId = mgr._id WHERE emp._id = ?", 
                                new String[]{""+employeeId});

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                employeeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeName);
                employeeName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstName")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastName")));

                employeeTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                employeeTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));

                officePhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.officePhone);
                officePhone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("officePhone")));

                cellPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellPhone);
                cellPhone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cellPhone")));

                email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
                email.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));

        }

    }

}
**DatabaseHelper.java**

package samples.employeedirectory;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employee_directory";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                /*
                 * Create the employee table and populate it with sample data.
                 * In step 6, we will move these hardcoded statements to an XML document.
                 */
                String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (" +
                                                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                                                "firstName TEXT, " +
                                                "lastName TEXT, " +
                                                "title TEXT, " +
                                                "officePhone TEXT, " +
                                                "cellPhone TEXT, " +
                                                "email TEXT, " +
                                                "managerId INTEGER)";
                db.execSQL(sql);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put("firstName", "John");
                values.put("lastName", "Smith");
                values.put("title", "CEO");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-2001");
                values.put("cellPhone", "617-456-7890");
                values.put("email", "jsmith@email.com");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Robert");
                values.put("lastName", "Jackson");
                values.put("title", "VP Engineering");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-3333");
                values.put("cellPhone", "781-444-2222");
                values.put("email", "rjackson@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "1");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Marie");
                values.put("lastName", "Potter");
                values.put("title", "VP Sales");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-2002");
                values.put("cellPhone", "987-654-3210");
                values.put("email", "mpotter@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "1");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Lisa");
                values.put("lastName", "Jordan");
                values.put("title", "VP Marketing");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-2003");
                values.put("cellPhone", "987-654-7777");
                values.put("email", "ljordan@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "2");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Christophe");
                values.put("lastName", "Coenraets");
                values.put("title", "Evangelist");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-0000");
                values.put("cellPhone", "617-666-7777");
                values.put("email", "ccoenrae@adobe.com");
                values.put("managerId", "2");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Paula");
                values.put("lastName", "Brown");
                values.put("title", "Director Engineering");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-612-0987");
                values.put("cellPhone", "617-123-9876");
                values.put("email", "pbrown@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "2");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Mark");
                values.put("lastName", "Taylor");
                values.put("title", "Lead Architect");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-444-1122");
                values.put("cellPhone", "617-555-3344");
                values.put("email", "mtaylor@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "2");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees");
                onCreate(db);
        }

}

and my XML files,

**main.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

**employee_list_item.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8px" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6px"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstName" />

</RelativeLayout>

**employee_details.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/employeeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/officePhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cellPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my logcat shows the following,

```
02-14 15:15:58.254: I/jdwp(599): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-14 15:15:59.443: D/AndroidRuntime(599): Shutting down VM
02-14 15:15:59.454: W/dalvikvm(599): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{samples.employeedirectory/samples.employeedirectory.EmployeeList}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at samples.employeedirectory.EmployeeList.onCreate(EmployeeList.java:25)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-14 15:15:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  ... 11 more
```

I would be thankful if someone help me out with as I am new to android technology

Comment: pasting the logcat and pointing to a specific line that throws that error will help us more than your entire project.

Comment: Logcat output required!!

Comment: please add Log of your error.

Comment: Thanks all, as asked i've posted my logcat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `main.xml` file. Change the ID of your ListView to use the "android" prefix:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Thanks @mark. But when I'm searching a particular contact there are no response. I'm quite sure a contact has to be fetched.

Comment: The exception in your logcat is for the reason I have given. You asked what is causing the Force Close, and that is precisely what I have answered.

Answer (score 0):

hey ur activity EmployeeList extending ListActivity and still u have done setContentView();

Do 1 thing

1. it should extend Activity
2. find ListView by FindViewById();
3. set adapter associated with it

Hope this will work